# Literal carriage return. Run script through tr -d '\r'

Tags: bash, shell, warnings

I'm executing a simple **Bash Script** and I got this warning on Visual Studio Code.

**Literal carriage return. Run script through tr -d '\r'**

I'm not sure if I must install an extension to solve it or it's a syntax error.

The code I'm using is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello"
```

I tried installing an extension in Visual Studio Code. I expect the warning to disappear.

Comment: In general, carriage return before newline will cause problems in shell scripts, so it's a syntax error. You don't need to install an extension, just do what the warning said. You do it from the Unix shell.

Comment: You can also use the `dos2unix` command.

Comment: But code editors have known about different line-ending formats for decades. Isn't there a option in VSC to force just `\n` line endings?